# Getting 'message successfully delivered' to the wrong mail address in Java Mail API

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have started implementing a mailing module using the JAVA mail API. Am using the SMTPMessage, so that i can get the delivery status of the mail. Problem is am getting successful delivery report for `wrong mail addresses`

This is what i have done to send the message

```
SMTPMessage smtpMsg=new SMTPMessage(message);
            smtpMsg.setReturnOption(SMTPMessage.RETURN_HDRS);
            smtpMsg.setNotifyOptions(SMTPMessage.NOTIFY_SUCCESS |SMTPMessage.NOTIFY_FAILURE);
            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            //attach the listeners for the connection and transmission
            transport.addConnectionListener(this);
            transport.addTransportListener(this);
            transport.connect();
            //connect to the server and send the message
            transport.sendMessage(smtpMsg, smtpMsg.getAllRecipients());
```

Since my class implements `TransportListener,ConnectionListener`, i have attached listeners as

```
public void opened(ConnectionEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Connection opened");
    }
    public void disconnected(ConnectionEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Connection disconnected");
    }
    public void closed(ConnectionEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Connection closed");
    }

    public void messageDelivered(TransportEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Message delivered for:");
        if (e != null) {
            Address[] a = e.getValidSentAddresses();
        if (a != null && a.length > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(((InternetAddress) a[i]).getAddress());
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
        }
    }

    public void messageNotDelivered(TransportEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Message not delivered for:");
        if (e != null) {
            Address[] a = e.getValidUnsentAddresses();
        if (a != null && a.length > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(((InternetAddress) a[i]).getAddress());
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
        }
    }

    public void messagePartiallyDelivered(TransportEvent e) {
        System.out.println("These addresses are invalid:");
        if (e != null) {
            Address[] a = e.getInvalidAddresses();
        if (a != null && a.length > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(((InternetAddress) a[i]).getAddress());
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
        }
    }
```

This is suggested in oe of the blogs. Whats wrong here? How can i get the delivery status as false for wrong mail IDS

This is how i am initializing the message

```
MimeMessage message=new MimeMessage(session);
        //set the mail sender address
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(userName));
        //set the recipient addresses
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(toAddr));
        //set subject of the mail
        message.setSubject(subject);
        //Set the body of the message
        message.setText(body);
```

Comment: Are the mail addresses syntactical wrong or are the addresses non-existant?

Comment: What kind of transport do you use?

Comment: What kind of message do you use?

Comment: As you can see in the code am using SMTPMessage, which takes the MimeMessage type as argument

Comment: I was guessing it takes string.

Comment: Put the code how do you initialize the message.

Comment: I think you shuld add try{...}catch(AddressException e){...} to capture that exception. I use this.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#badaddr